# Restriction of measure on two set the same implies both Borel

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This question was raised when I read Evans' textbook *Measure theory and Fine Properties of Functions*.

In the proof of theorem 1.7 (see below for the theorem), he let $\mu$ be a Borel regular measure, $A\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $\mu-measurable$ set, and $B$ be a Borel set such that $A\subset B$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$. Then with some efforts he showed that $\mu\llcorner B=\mu\llcorner A$, and conclude that WLOG we may assume $A$ is a Borel set.

I'm wondering why we can assume $A$ to be Borel here; can someone explain it a little bit with elementary measure theory knowledge? Thanks in advance.

Theorem: Let $\mu$ be a Borel regular measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mu-measurable$ and $\mu(A)<\infty$; then $\mu\llcorner A$ is a Radon measure.

Clarification of $\mu-measurable$: in this book, a set $A\subset X$ is said to be $\mu-measurable$ if for any $B\subset X$, we have $\mu(B)=\mu(B\bigcap A)+\mu(B\bigcap A^{\mathsf{c}})$

Comment: What does $\mu$-measurable mean? I may be wrong, but I have only seen it for outer measures. In any case, I think that (unless one knows exactly what you are talking about) when one reads “… WLOG we can assume…”, he/she should know what you want to prove, otherwise that makes no sense

Comment: I mean, the book is not saying that $A$ is Borel thanks to the fact that the measures on $A$ and $B$ coincide. Is saying that if you prove the theorem assuming furthermore $A$ Borel, then you are authomatically done

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Thanks for your comment; but I'm still quite confused about why we only need to prove the case when A is Borel.

Comment: What I say is that you should write down the theorem in order to get help for that

Comment: uh...thanks; I've edited my question and add a definition to the $\mu-measurable$ mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It was just a bit strange to me to read $\mu$-measurable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost immedite. A detailed proof should sound like this:

“…WLOG, we can assume in addition A to be a Borel set, meaning that we just need to prove the theorem for Borel sets. In fact, if A is a general measurable set, we can choose B as before and (if we know that the theorem is true for Borel sets), since B is Borel, we know that $\mu\llcorner B$ is a Radon measure. So, since $\mu\llcorner A = \mu\llcorner B$, we conclude.
Now, let’s prove the theorem assuming A is Borel…”

Comment: Thank you for your answer; this step is clear for me now.